# Doing a bifurcation analysis of a system of couple ODEs with many parameters

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

Although I tried looked at severals posts and documents, all that I found was how to solve a two equation system. Therefore, I don't know if it possible to me perform one bifurcation analysis with ODE's of multiple variables. Like this case:

```
sys = 
  {S'[t] == (r* S[t] - ((r*S[t]^2)/NN)- ((r*S[t]*II[t])/NN) - S[t]*alpha*V[t]), 
   II'[t] == alpha*S[t]*V[t] - a*II[t] - delta*II[t], 
   V'[t] == n1*d1*II[t] - d4*V[t], 
   P'[t] == 
     delta*II[t] + P[t] - (theta*(P[t]^2)/(KK^2 + P[t]^2)) - 
     kp1*EE[t]*P[t] + (kp2 + kcp*(1 - p1))*Cp[t] - ka*P[t]*A[t],  
   CC'[t] == ((theta*P[t]^2)/(KK^2 + P[t]^2)) - k1*CC[t], 
   EE'[t] == 
     s1 - dr1*EE[t] + ((f*(Cp[t] + Ca[t]))/(g + P[t])) - kp1*EE[t]*P[t] + 
     (kp2 + kcp*p1)*Cp[t] - kl1*L[t]*EE[t] + kl2*Ca[t] + kca*Ca[t] + 2*ke2*Ce[t] - 
     2*ke1*EE[t]^2 + kce*Ce[t], 
   A'[t] == s2 - dr2*A[t] - ka*P[t]*A[t] + kl*L[t],  
   L'[t] == ka*P[t]*A[t] - kl*L[t] - kl1*L[t]*EE[t] + kl2*Ca[t], 
   Cp'[t] == kp1*EE[t]*P[t] - (kp2 + kcp)*Cp[t], 
   Ca'[t] == kl1*L[t]*EE[t] - (kl2 + kca)*Ca[t], 
   Ce'[t] == ke1*EE[t]^2 - (ke2 + kce)*Ce[t], 
   S[0] == 10^+6,  II[0] == 0, V[0] == 10^+2, P[0] == 0, CC[0] == 0, EE[0] == 0, 
   A[0] == 0, L[0] == 0, Cp[0] == 0, Ca[0] == 0, Ce[0] == 0};
```

The parameters are

```
r = 0.02; 
delta = 0.0082; 
d4 = 50;  
a = 0.01;  
b = 1; 
alpha = 0.0001; 
k1 = 1.01; 
NN = 10^6; 
KK = (NN/1.344); 
theta = 2.03*KK; 
n1 = 100; 
d1 = 10000/(n1*NN); 
s1 =  1.36*10^4; 
dr1 = 0.0412; 
g = 2.02*10^7; 
kp1 = 1.3*10^-7;  kp2 = 24; kcp = 7.2;
p1 = 0.9997; 
kl1 = 1.3*10^-7; kl2 = 24; kca = 7.2; 
ke1 = 24; ke2 = 1.3*10^-7; 
kce = 7.2; 
ka = 0.5*10^-6; 
s2 = 1.36*10^4; 
dr2 = 0.0412; 
kl = 10.0; 
f = 0.2988*10^8;
```

I am interested in varying five variables (`NN`, `KK`, `d1`, `theta` ,and any other) with respect to time. Due to these three parameters being coupled and,
taking into consideration the complexity of the system, I don't have the knowlegde to meet my aim.

When I varying the values for `NN` and `S`, I must change `KK`, `d1`, `theta`. `V[0] == 10^+2` stays the same during all the simulations, and the others variables equal to zero, Then:

```
S=NN = 10^2, KK = 74.4047619047619 d1 = 10^0  theta = 151.041666666667
S=NN = 10^3, KK = 744.047619047619 d1 = 10^-1 theta = 1510.41666666667
S=NN = 10^4, KK = 7440.47619047619 d1 = 10^-2 theta = 15104.1666666667
S=NN = 10^5, KK = 74404.7619047619 d1 = 10^-3 theta = 151041.666666667
S=NN = 10^6, KK = 744047.619047619 d1 = 10^-4 theta = 1510416.66666667
S=NN = 10^7, KK = 7440476.19047619 d1 = 10^-5 theta = 15104166.6666667
S=NN = 10^8, KK = 74404761.9047619 d1 = 10^-6 theta = 151041666.666667
```

**Aclaration: The expression above is only to explain the set the values used in each simulation. For example, when I say `S=NN = 10^2` I want to say that the initial condition `S'[0] = 10^2` and the constant value  for `NN= 10^2`**

I performed the simulations for each one set of parameters, the behaivor of my system for the variables P and A are similiar of this way:

[image: Values of NN between 10^2 and 10^8]

And now, 
`S=NN = 10^9, KK = 744047619.047619 d1 = 10^-7  theta = 1510416666.66667`

The behaivor of the equations are  asymptotic:

[image: Asymptotic system for NN = 10^9]

Continuing the simulations

```
S=NN = 10^10, KK = 7440476190.47619 d1 = 10^-8  theta = 15104166666.6667
S=NN = 10^11, KK = 74404761904.7619 d1 = 10^-9  theta = 151041666666.667
S=NN = 10^12, KK = 744047619047.619 d1 = 10^-10 theta = 1510416666666.67
```

[image: Behaivor of equation system for values of NN between 10^10 and 10^12]

Finally:

```
S=NN = 10^13, KK = 7440476190476.19 d1 = 10^-11  theta = 15104166666666.7
```

[image: Beahivor for NN = 10^13]

How you can see, this last simulation attracts all my interest, due to firstly oscillations and then her state semi-stable

And I want to visualizate the phase diagram for the different variables and  identify their nullclines associated.

Could you help me to form an idea of how to plotting a phase portrait and interpreter this results?.

Comment: Could you say how you would like to vary those parameters and what you mean by "visualize the phase diagram"?  Also, `N` and `K` are reserved by Mathematica, better to avoid using them.

Comment: Hello @ChrisK, thanks you, I had to changed theses names. Although the problem no are the names of the parameters, the problem is found in knowed the set of functions for represent bifurcation analysis

Comment: I think you have an `E[t]` instead of an `EE[t]`. Anyway, I'm not an expert in bifurcation but I would expect the bifurcation points to coincide with singularities of the jacobian. So you could start by finding the jacobian?

Comment: Could you clarify what results you want?  What are on the x- and y-axes of the plots?

Comment: @ChrisK.  I modified the post trying became more clarify, thanks you very much for spending your time on this

Comment: @anderstood the problem is specifictly in the last simulation :( I don't know how perform the bifurcation analysis, thanks you

Comment: A few more comments & questions: 1) Mathematica doesn't understand notation like `1.36e+04` for scientific notation, use `1.36*^4`.  2) `alfa` should be `alpha`.  3) `S` is a variable, it can't be set equal to `NN`.  4) How did you get your figures?

Comment: Hello @ChrisK. I fix the mistakes to the points 1 and 2 of your list of comments. I added one note aclaratory in the post about your point 3 "The expression above is only to explain the set the values used in each simulation. It is not the real expression to use in mathematica". About the point 4 I should have used matlab with rk-4, because in mathematica 10 my pc does not have enough memory to calculate these results